# $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{{(1-\cos{(x)})}^{10}\cos{(10x)}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can you help me with this? I tried to apply partial integration but got no results; I also looked at a few tactics about the integrals of high-grade expressions, I couldn't find a stylish move.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{{(1-\cos{(x)})}^{10}\cos{(10x)}}dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the following holds:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos(x))^n\cos(nx)\,dx = (-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}.
$$
So in your case, you get $\frac{\pi}{512}$ as the solution. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710144/prove-int-02-pi1-cos-xn-cos-nx-dx-1n-frac-pi2n-1) for a proof of this identity.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos x)^n \cos n x dx
\\
=Re \int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos x)^n e^{i n x}dx
\\
=Re \frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^{2\pi}(2e^{ix}-e^{2i x}-1)^n dx
\\
=Re (-1)^n\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{ix}-1)^{2n}dx
$$
We know
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}dx=0,n=1,2,3...
$$
So
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos x)^n \cos n x dx
\\
=Re (-1)^n\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{ix}-1)^{2n}dx
\\
=\frac{(-1)^n\pi}{2^{n-1}}
$$